# NextJS route.ts is rebundled

Tags: next.js, next.js13

So I am using NextJS in my project. I created a custom server with this documentation: https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/configuring/custom-server . I created the routes and also imported the JavaScript files that I initialize in the backend.

Now the thing that is not working is that Next is somehow rebundling the imported files and thus they are separate entities. This may be also why a simple API request that creates an entity in the database takes 5 seconds.

Is it possible to tell Next to simply use the Node cache where the variables are correctly initialized?

I am using:

- AppRouter
- Turbo

Comment: Ok I found out that it tries to bundle the JavaScript file as if it would be a static site. Why does this happen?